# In a semigroup $S=\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$, any product $a_1 * \ldots * a_i, 1 \le i \le n$ is unique

Tags: induction, semigroups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one actually show from associativity that one can drop parentheses?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21581/how-does-one-actually-show-from-associativity-that-one-can-drop-parentheses)

**Claim:** Let $(S, *)$ be a semigroup and $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in S$. Then $a_1 * \ldots * a_n$ is unique.

I'm having trouble proving this claim, because I'm a beginner, I'm sure, and would like some guidance if you please. Here's my attempt so far:

**Edit:** Following AndréNicolas advice, here's my second attempt.

**Proof:** My strategy is the following. Given a set S of elements:

1. Define the set of all products;
2. Define the set of all normalized products;
3. Show how we can normalize all products;
4. Show that all products are equal to their normalized version.

---

*Step 1: Define the set of all products:*

Let $*_S$, the set of all products over $S$, be defined inductively as follows:

- $a \in *_S$, if $a \in S$;
- $(a * x) \in *_S$, if $a \in S$ and $x \in *_S$;
- $(x * a) \in *_S$, if $a \in S$ and $x \in *_S$

---

*Step 2: Define the set of all normalized products:*

Let $\star_S$, the set of all normalized products over $S$, be defined inductively as follows:

- $a \in \star_S$, if $a \in S$;
- $(a * x) \in \star_S$, if $a \in S$ and $x \in \star_S$

---

*Step 3: Show how we can normalize all products:*

Let $\searrow_S: *_S \to \star_S$ be the following application, also defined inductively:

$\begin{array}{rcl}
a & \mapsto & a
\\ (a * x) & \mapsto & (a * \searrow_S(x))
\\ (x * a) & \mapsto & \begin{cases}
(a\prime * a) &, \searrow_S(x) = a\prime
\\
(a\prime * \searrow_S(y * a)) & , \searrow_S(x) = (a\prime * y)
\end{cases}
\end{array}$

---

*Step 4: Show that all products are equal to their normalized version:*

This proceeds by strong induction over $*_S$. Let $\Phi(x) \equiv x = \searrow_S(x)$.

- $a = \searrow_S(a) \equiv a = a$;
- Suppose $x = \searrow_S(x)$. It's left to show that $(a * x) = \searrow_S(a * x) \equiv (a * x) = (a * \searrow_S(x)) \equiv (a * x) = (a * x)$.
- Suppose $x = \searrow_S(x)$. It's left to show that $(x * a) = \searrow_S(x * a)$. There are two cases:

  - $\searrow_S(x) = a\prime$. Then $(x * a) = \searrow_S(x * a) \equiv (a\prime * a) = (a\prime * a)$.
  - $\searrow_S(x) = (a\prime * y)$. Then $(x * a) = \searrow_S(x * a) \equiv ((a\prime * y) * a) = (a\prime * \searrow_S(y * a))$. **and this where I am stuck now.** I am not sure how strong induction plays, in order to develop this further. Can you please criticise what I've done so far?

---

Thanks for taking the time to read this question of mine.
Best wishes,

Comment: Working with no parentheses may be confusing. Define "normal form" by saying it is something like $a(b(c(de)))$ (all left parentheses pushed as far left as possible). Show by (strong) induction that any product is equal to a normal form product.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thanks, I will try that and come back later to report on my findings.

Comment: The claim here comes as a little more clearly stated in my opinion than in the linked thread of Arturo's, but I do agree that it seems like a duplicate.