# Please explain the proof of the generalized associative property for the case of 4 variables.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I have seen the inductive proof and can't make sense of it.  I thought it should be easy to show for $4$ variables.

Here is my way of using the associative property to cover all the cases of $4$ variables:

$$a((bc)d)=(a(bc))d=((ab)c)d=(ab)(cd)=a(b(cd))$$

I don't see how all these terms can be shown to be equal in one fell swoop.

Comment: It's hard to tell what sort of answer you're looking for here. In addition, abstract algebra and algebra/precalculus are really, really far away from one another, which makes it harder to tell specifically what you're asking for. Can you clarify? ---- In a proof, you don't have to prove everything at one go. If you prove $A=B$ and $B=C$ (and your system obeys the transitive property) then you have $A=C$.

Comment: As explained [here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/21711/242) the inductive step pushes ')'s rightward via the rewrite rule $\rm\, (xy)z\ \to\ x(yz),\,$ terminating with the *right-associated normal form* where all ')'s are at the right end. In OP this yields 

$$\begin{align}((ab)c)d &= (ab)(cd) = a(b(cd))\\[.3em]
(a(bc))d &=a((bc)d) = a(b(cd))\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

What don't you understand in the linked general proofs?