# Prove composition of $n$ mappings is generalized associative

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, function-and-relation-composition

I have difficulties with this task in linear algebra:

By mathematical induction, prove: let any finite mapping $f_1$,$f_2$,$\cdots$,$f_n$ exist. If for any $1\leqslant i\leqslant n-1$, the domain of $f_{i+1}$ equals the codomain of $f_i$, the composition of functions is always generalized associative. That is to say, the result of $f_n\circ\cdots\circ f_2\circ f_1$ is independent of how the expression is bracketed.

For example: $$((f_4\circ f_3)\circ f_2)\circ f_1=(f_4\circ f_3)\circ(f_2\circ f_1)=(f_4\circ(f_3\circ f_2))\circ f_1=f_4\circ((f_3\circ f_2)\circ f_1)=f_4\circ(f_3\circ(f_2\circ f_1)).$$

It is already proved that for $n=3$, the statement holds. My attempt is as follows.

Assume for any given case $3\leqslant n\leqslant k (n\in\mathbb{N}^*,k\geqslant3,k\in\mathbb{N}^*)$ the statement holds. Then while $n=k+1$, $$f_{k+1}\circ\cdots\circ f_2\circ f_1=(f_{k+1}\circ\cdots)\circ(f_{i+1}\circ f_{i})\circ(\cdots\circ f_2\circ f_1)=\underbrace{(f_{k+1}\circ\cdots)\circ(g)\circ(\cdots\circ f_2\circ f_1)}_{k\text{ terms}},$$ and $1\leqslant i\leqslant k$, $i\in\mathbb{N}^*$, so the statement applies too.

I want to know if:

1. There are any corrections to be made, and
2. Better wording for the proof.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: More generally (and perhaps easier to conceptualize) is the fact that any associative binary operation satisfies "generalized associativity". See [How does one actually show from associativity that one can drop parentheses?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/21581/13130) and my 12 September 2006 sci.math post [Combinatorics of associativity](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/MQRGtT7kVKE/m/TIIQ7C7O7vQJ).